# preg_replace with space (or nothing) before

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to create a function to detect links from a string, but only if before www. is nothing or is whitespace.

First Case:
I have this string: I go to www.google.com

In this case, my PHP function detects www.google.com

In the second case I have this string: I go a href="http://www.google.com"
Script doesn't detect www.google.com because is included in another "word", that fine.

But in last case, I have only wwww.google.com (without any whitespace or anything else). The problem is that now my function doesn't detect www.google.com because there is no space before the string. How can I fix that?

This is what I use:

```
$text = preg_replace('/([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/i', 
       '\\1<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $text);
```

Comment: Try `$text = preg_replace('/([[:space:]()[{}])?(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/i', 
       '\\1<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $text);`

Comment: Looks like @Deer-Outdoor.nl mentioned the ? and I know this isn't regex but the DOM/Xpath route is far more reliable IMO.

Comment: I know about ? I've tried already, but will no longer work in second case and that's a problem.

Comment: If the is a string before URL, I want to be detected the whitespace (I don't want to get the url from a word like: asbcwww.) but if is only the www. (without anything else), then is a problem because there is no whitespace and doesn't detect it.